# Using Array method `.reduce()`, please write the logic to loop through an array of objects and return with the analysis

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript reduce method.

I need help in solving below question

Using Array method `.reduce()`, please write the logic to loop through an array of objects and return with the analysis:

```js
const orders = [
    {  doctorId: 996, amount: 30500.35, tax: 0.06, isDisputed: true, isShipped: true },
    {  doctorId: 910, amount: 100, tax: 0.08, isDisputed: true },
    {  doctorId: 912, amount: 4200.11, tax: 0.06 },
    {  doctorId: 996, amount: 99.12, tax: 0.06, isDisputed: false },
    {  doctorId: 910, amount: 0.00, tax: 0.08, isShipped: true },
    {  doctorId: 996, amount: 10, tax: 0.06, isDisputed: true },
];

// Expected result to be an object and have keys:
// - Total number of orders
// - Total disputed orders
// - Total disputed amount (included tax)
// - Total amount (included tax)
// - Total unique users
// - Total average sales per unique user
const result = collections.reduce(...);

console.log(result);
```

I tried like this

`const totalDisputedOrders = orders.reduce((acc, { isDisputed }) => isDisputed === true ? acc += 1 : acc, 0);`

but was confused about how to declare the initial result object in reduce

Comment: If you're learning you need to at least attempt it, so far you've only given us the data and asked us to do the actual task for you, give it a shot you'll be surprised what you're capable of!

Comment: Yes, right. I should go through documentation

Answer (score 1):

Although I won't complete the exercise for you, here is a hint on how you can get started.

```js
const orders = [
    {
        doctorId: 996,
        amount: 30500.35,
        tax: 0.06,
        isDisputed: true,
        isShipped: true,
    },
    { doctorId: 910, amount: 100, tax: 0.08, isDisputed: true },
    { doctorId: 912, amount: 4200.11, tax: 0.06 },
    { doctorId: 996, amount: 99.12, tax: 0.06, isDisputed: false },
    { doctorId: 910, amount: 0.0, tax: 0.08, isShipped: true },
    { doctorId: 996, amount: 10, tax: 0.06, isDisputed: true },
];

// Expected result to be an object and have keys:
// - Total number of orders
// - Total disputed orders
// - Total disputed amount (included tax)
// - Total amount (included tax)
// - Total unique users
// - Total average sales per unique user
const result = orders.reduce(
    (result, item) => {
        // here you have access to the previous computed metrics thus far (using result) and the curent order (using item)

        // here's how you would do the first one, as an example
        const numberOfOrders = result.numberOfOrders + 1;

        // ... compute the rest of the metrics here ...

        return {
            numberOfOrders,
            // ... return the rest of the results here ...
        };
    },
    {
        numberOfOrders: 0,
        disputedOrders: 0,
        disputedAmount: 0,
        totalAmount: 0,
        uniqueUsers: 0,
        averageSalesPerUser: 0,
    },
);

console.log(result);
```

If you don't understand what is going on, the first place to read would be [the `Array.prototype.reduce()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried like this const totalDisputedOrders = orders.reduce((acc, { isDisputed }) => isDisputed === true ? acc += 1 : acc, 0); but was confused about how to declare the initial result object in reduce

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) In the future, you should post information about what you have tried in the question to give a little more context. If you frame it more specifically then the question won't get closed/downvoted as much.